# Return 0 and null for 0 fetched rows postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql

I have the following SQL query below, it executes without errors, and is functional, the only thing it is not doing is returning 0 for INT and NULL columns for VARCHAR columns when the query return is 0 rows

**QUERY**

```
SELECT
    coalesce((tb_get_customers.customer), 'null') as "CUSTOMER", 
    coalesce((COUNT(*)),0) as "METRICS", 
    coalesce((CONCAT('STATUS: ', severity)), 'null') as "SEVERITY"
FROM 
    tb_get_faults left 
    JOIN tb_get_customers ON tb_get_faults.customer = tb_get_customers.cust_cmdb 
WHERE 
    tb_get_faults.exception = 'NO' 
    AND tb_get_faults.type = 'VM' 
    AND tb_get_faults.customer = 'CLIENT1' 
    AND tb_get_faults.severity= 'HIGH' 
GROUP BY 
    tb_get_faults.customer, 
    tb_get_customers.customer, 
    tb_get_faults.impact 
ORDER BY 
    tb_get_customers.customer ASC;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**DESERIED OUTPUT**

```
------------------------------
CUSTOMER | METRICS | SEVERITY
------------------------------
  null   |    0    |   null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `CTE` with your query:

```
with CTE as (
  <your query here>
)
select * from cte
union all
select 'null', 0, 'null'
where not exists (select 1 from cte)
```

The 2nd query of `UNION ALL` will return the row that you expect when the `CTE` does not return any rows.

Comment: I tested with CTE, however returned " ERROR: relation "cte" does not exist "

Comment: I just added the query within CTE

Comment: This is how it works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=04b3de4236dbcaf00a8c6322556b2d80

Answer (score 1):

Your-re doing `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. Probably your `tb_get_faults` table contains data that are returned.

The columns that you're getting don't contains columns from `tb_get_faults` table.

Try to put all columns that you're choosing on your `group by` clause in select, you gonna see exactly what the aggregation are doing.

If you want to show only if you have data on select, change the `LEFT JOIN` to  `INNER JOIN`

Comment: I tested with INNER JOIN returns equal values of the question